# How to make an addressable getter that casts from an interface

Tags: go

I have the concept of `Context` which is a map that can hold any structure. Basically, I want to create a generic getter that **adddressably** 'populates' the destination interface (similarly to how json decoding works).

Here's an example of how I want this to work:

```
type Context map[string]interface{}

// Random struct that will be saved in the context
type Step struct { 
    Name string
}

func main() {
    stepA := &Step{Name: "Cool Name"}

    c := Context{}
    c["stepA"] = stepA

    var stepB *Step
    err := c.Get("stepA", stepB)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(stepB.Name) // Cool Name
    stepB.Name = "CoolName2"

    fmt.Println(stepA.Name) // I want to say: CoolName2
}

func (c Context) Get(stepId string, dest interface{}) error {
    context, ok := c[stepId]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    destinationValue := reflect.ValueOf(dest)
    contextValue := reflect.ValueOf(context)

    destinationValue.Set(contextValue) // Errors here
    return nil
}
```

I leaned towards using reflect, but maybe I don't need it? - so opened to other suggestions (except for generics as that complicates other matters) I'm getting the following error with the above:

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value
```

You can test it [here](https://go.dev/play/p/WG-4guO1EpW).

Comment: Same problem as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74029743/go-lang-how-to-reference-a-new-pointer-to-a-current-pointer the only difference is that you're using reflection, however reflection will not fix the problem. You need to pass a non-nil pointer to the Get method, no exceptions.

Comment: @mkopriva can you get to a working solution? I tried not using reflection but I couldn't get it working

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/oEl36ANyzd6 Basically if you were to do this without reflection for only a single type, let's say `string` you would pass a non-nil pointer to a string value, i.e. `*string` to the function and then, when you want to update the data to which the pointer points you would do `*v = "new string"`, the `*v` is in this case pointer indirection. In reflection this is achieved by using `Elem()`. as you can see in the example.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks. I got to this solution earlier but unfortunately it's not addressable - `stepA.Name` does not reflect the change at the end

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/5556Ydls1Qy -- Sorry, didn't notice that you were trying to also update stepA through stepB. In such a case you have to use pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @mkopriva Ahh so simple haha. Thank you! I assume I can enforce the passing of an empty pointer to `Get` by checking the reflect Kind (twice I guess?). Feel free to post the solution as an answer and I'll accept! A bit of a side question but is this use of reflect performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to Get must be a pointer type whose element type is identical to the type in the context map. So if the value in the context map is of type `*Step`, then the argument's type must be `**Step`. Also the passed in argument cannot be `nil`, it can be a pointer to `nil`, but it itself cannot be `nil`.

So in your case you should do:

```golang
var stepB *Step
err := c.Get("stepA", &stepB) // pass pointer-to-pointer
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

And the `Get` method, fixed up a bit:

```golang
func (c Context) Get(stepId string, dest interface{}) error {
    context, ok := c[stepId]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    dv := reflect.ValueOf(dest)
    if dv.Kind() != reflect.Ptr || dv.IsNil() {
        return errors.New("dest must be non-nil pointer")
    }

    dv = dv.Elem()
    cv := reflect.ValueOf(context)
    if dv.Type() != cv.Type() {
        return errors.New("dest type does not match context value type")
    }

    dv.Set(cv)
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/OECttqp1aVg